# simplify $\sqrt{3+2\sqrt{2}}-\sqrt{4-2\sqrt{3}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, nested-radicals

Simplify $\sqrt{3+2\sqrt{2}}-\sqrt{4-2\sqrt{3}}$

To do it I have see it that we have basically $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$ that is we can write it as,

$$\sqrt{\sqrt{3}\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2}}-\sqrt{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2}\sqrt{3}}$$

But even with that I don't get that result.

Comment: Find $a,b$ such that $(a+b\sqrt{2})^2 = 3+2\sqrt{2}$, and $c,d$ such that $(c+d\sqrt{3})^2 = 4 - 2\sqrt{3}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can recognize both expressions as squares:

- $3+2\sqrt2=2+2\sqrt2+1=(\sqrt2)^2+2\cdot \sqrt2\cdot 1+1^2=(\sqrt2+1)^2$, and
- $4-2\sqrt3=3-2\sqrt3+1=(\sqrt3-1)^2$.

This means that $\sqrt{3+2\sqrt2}-\sqrt{4-2\sqrt3}=\sqrt2+1-(\sqrt3-1)=2+\sqrt2-\sqrt3$.

Comment: in wolfram alpha I get 2+sqrt2-sqrt3

Comment: Yes, also here. (Typos fixed.)

Comment: Why a full solution?

Comment: @Did It looked cute and simple enough. (There are plenty of nice questions that reduce to simplifications of this sort, so I have a soft spot for some of them.)

Comment: The *beginning* is cute, yes, but the last line, frankly?

Comment: @Did Hehe. The problem *looked* cute.

Answer (score 7):

Hints:
$$3+2\sqrt2=(\sqrt2)^2+2\sqrt2+1\qquad 4-2\sqrt3=(\sqrt3)^2-2\sqrt3+1$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sqrt{3+2\sqrt2}=\sqrt{3+\sqrt8}=\sqrt\frac{3+\sqrt{9-8}}{2}+\sqrt\frac{3-\sqrt{9-8}}{2}=\sqrt2+1$$
$$\sqrt{4-2\sqrt3}=\sqrt{4-\sqrt12}=\sqrt\frac{4+\sqrt{16-12}}{2}-\sqrt\frac{4-\sqrt{16-12}}{2}=\sqrt3-1$$
Now we have:
$$\sqrt{3+2\sqrt2}-\sqrt{4-2\sqrt3}=\sqrt2+1-(\sqrt3-1)=\sqrt2+2-\sqrt3$$